# Spring boot. Mapping 2 seperate project controllers ignoring a project

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, that loads the configurations of 2 other projects as follows:

The application annotation: `@ImportResource("path/to/xml/config.xml")`

Which maps to the config.xml containing :

```
<import resource="classpath:path/to/project1/config.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:path/to/project2/config.xml"/>
```

These config.xml's contain the following lines respectively :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.project1.package" />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.project2.package" />
```

Within those packages I have a controller:

Project 1 controller

```
package my.project1.package;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project1")
@SessionAttributes("batchNumber")
public class Project1Controller { 
    @RequestMapping(value="/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sampleMethod() {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

and Project 2 controller:

```
package my.project2.package;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project2")
@SessionAttributes("batchNumber")
public class Project2Controller { 
    @RequestMapping(value="/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sampleMethod() {
        return "hi2";
    }
}
```

Yes, the method names and their mappings need to be the same, only the class's ReqeustMapping is different.

When I start my application using Spring Boot.

I get the `Mapped [/project1/sample]` line which works fine, however the `/project2/sample` never gets mapped.

Is there a possible reason why these controllers aren't getting mapped/scanned?

Comment: If it isn't registered it isn't scanned. Also the mappings aren't the same as it is the full path that counts, if the mapping would be the same you would get an error.

Comment: Any idea if something else is required apart from the above listed for the mapping to be done? I can compare projects to see differences but I don't know where to look

Comment: Make sure that scanning is really correct. Spring Boot should give you a list of mapped URLs to which controller/method. If the second isn't in there it simply isn't detected by the component-scan.

Comment: yes the issue was in fact I had a wrong package listed. didn't notice it cause of similar naming. Thanks a lot. Feel free to post an answer. Though as such, the above question samples work already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments above

Had a wrong package listed in the context scan